# import com.google.ads.*; doesn't have AdManager

Tags: eclipse, cordova, admob, google-ad-manager

I'm really stuck here, trying to set a banner with ads-admob to my android app. I have done all the layout settings in the main.xml, also worked in the manifest file with the permissions, tried both XML and JAVA methods to show the ads and trying to make it work but I always get "could not get currentAdManager" from logcat in Eclipse. The application also crashes here, but works just fine without the admob settings. My admob SDK is GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.0.1.jar and I'm developing using phonegap .

I noticed that the command "import com.google.ads.*;" doesn't have  the "AdManager" because when I insert individually the "import com.google.ads.AdManager;", I receive the error message "The import com.google.ads.AdManager cannot be resolved". My files:

**My JAVA:**

```
>     package what.car.notes;
>     
>     import android.os.Bundle;
>     import org.apache.cordova.*;
>     import com.google.ads.AdView;
>     import com.google.ads.AdManager; **- ERROR APEARS HERE**
>     import com.google.ads.*;
>     
>     public class Cargeous21forActivity extends DroidGap {
>         /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>         @Override
>         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>             super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
>             setContentView(R.layout.main);
>             
>             dView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.AdView);
>       adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
>         }
>     }
```

**My LAYOUT file (main.xml):**

```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     
>     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/what.car.notes"
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>         
>     <com.admob.android.ads.AdView
>     android:id="@+id/AdView"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
>     myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
>     myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
>     /> 
>     
>     </LinearLayout>
```

**My MANIFEST:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="what.car.notes"
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.3" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-library
    android:name="com.google.ads.AdManager" />

<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

<meta-data android:value="i've put my correct id here" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />

<activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
                android:value="SQLite-NDK"  />
        <!-- Track Market installs -->
<receiver android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver"
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

And finally, the attrs.xml:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> <declare-styleable
> name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView"> <attr name="backgroundColor"
> format="color" /> <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
> <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" /> <attr
> name="keywords" format="string" /> <attr name="refreshInterval"
> format="integer" /> </declare-styleable> </resources>
```

Does anyone have already been through such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [getting started](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/banner_xml) guide for the Google AdMob SDK on Android.  The example from which you got that code is from an old Google ads SDK before the Google AdMob Ads SDK rewrite.

Issues I can see on first pass:

1. You're manifest's activity definition is incorrect.  See [this page](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals#incorporating) for the correct AdActivity activity definition.
2. You don't need attrs.xml.  The SDK includes these attributes now.
3. I don't think the publisher id can be a meta-vale.  You must specify the publisher id in your AdView XML definition.
4. Your AdView XML definition needs to have an adSize.
5. The new Google AdMob SDK doesn't have a com.google.ads.AdManager class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eric! Your answer helped me a lot to find the right code. The final code looks like this:

JAVA:

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.google.ads.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.LinearLayout; 


public class myactActivity extends DroidGap {

     private static final String MY_AD_UNIT_ID = "a14fd7e04e46295"; 
     private AdView adView; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");


        //
     // Create the adView 
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID); 
        LinearLayout layout = super.root; // this is the only change from the sample 
        // Add the adView to it 
        layout.addView(adView); 
        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad 
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); 

    }    
    }
```

My layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

<com.google.ads.GoogleAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

EVerthing worked since then... BUT! YEs, there is a but... 2 days later, with the incredible amount of $0,00 and 150 ads solicitacion, admob/google canceled my account!! I had heard their method are weird and remove developers for no reason at all and, with $0,00 and 150 views they cut me off of their program. Good part: I found some other ad services better than admob, but the minus side is that I'll have to figure out the code all over again...

Thanks anyway Eric!

Comment: If @EricLeichtenschlag answer is correct, then mark it as such ideally with an up vote.  You should not post follow-ups as answers with additional questions.